# Register an event on resizing

Tags: angular, angular-material2, mat-tab

When a Component is placed in a non selected Material Tab, it's in a disconnected DOM state, and its dimensions are 0. When the tab is selected, it is added to the DOM, and gets a real dimension. I need to intercept this event from inside the added component. How can I bind to either "added to dom" event, or "dimensions change"?

P.S. `Resize` event doesn't work, because its for window, not specific element/view.

Comment: Tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resize-event?

Comment: just tried, didn't work :(